# How can I set a tkinter app icon with a URL?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

If I have:

```
from Tkinter import *
app = Tk()

...

app.mainloop()
```

Would I use `app.iconbitmap(...)`?

And if so, how would I go about using [this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qtlincxkbbiz1qv/stat.gif) as the file, and should I import `urllib`?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a stored image that will be a hyperlink to a URL, or do you want to retrieve an image from a URL that will be used as an icon?

Comment: I have [this link](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/iu8w1dz3fsnly2i/stat.ico) and I need it to be retrieved via the URL. @alex-thornton

Comment: Yeah, I want it in the place of the `tk` icon, and also in the windows taskbar when its opened. If that's possible. @alex-thornton

Comment: I am pretty sure it would be possible if you were putting it in the main program display, but I don't think it is for the program icon. At least I don't know how. Sorry.

Comment: I can tell you for certain that changing the taskbar icon is impossible. Python is an interpreted language, so python.exe runs, not your program on its own. Therefore the icon will be the Python icon unless you find some way to edit the icon of compiled code.

Comment: I just used [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to change the compiled `py2exe` version. @alex-thornton

Comment: Well, PyInstaller lets you change the icon so you don't have to go through that mess. Run it with `--icon=myfile.ico`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this too replace the `Tkinter` default icon.

```
import base64, PIL, urllib, Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from urllib import *

root = Tk()

raw_data = urllib.urlopen("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qtlincxkbbiz1qv/stat.gif").read()

b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
image = PhotoImage(data=b64_data)

root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, image)

root.mainloop()
```

And then change the `.py` file extension to `.pyw` to change the taskbar icon.

The `.pyw` extension tells it to run with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`, but running with `pythonw.exe` also makes it run without the console.

So, you'll either have to run without the icon, or without the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is the call that worked for me on both Windows and Linux. I found that I cannot use ico files on Linux, so only using gif files which works on both platforms.

```
class Editor(tk.Tk):
   . . .
   . . . 
   self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, tk.PhotoImage(file = "my_icon.gif"))
```