# Can't fetch weather icons from openweathermap

Tags: python, api, tkinter, openweathermap

I have been trying to fetch weather icons from `openweathermap` api for a python application, but for some reason I am not able to do so.

I am however, able to print the icon as text for e.g. its code like `"3d"` or `"3n"` but not the image.

When I try to print the image, the error `_tkinter.TclError: image "03n" doesn't exist` pops up.

My code is below.

```
import requests
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x250+0+0")
root.configure(bg='black')
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=c73d9cdb31fd6a386bee66158b116cd0&q=karachi&units=metric'

json = requests.get(url).json()
temperature = json['main']['temp']
icon = json['weather'][0]['icon']
#icon1 = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png'
#print(icon)
root.lab1 = Label(root,image=icon)
root.lab1.pack(side=TOP)
root.lab= Label(text=(root,'{} deg celcius'.format(temperature)),font=("Helvetica 15"), bg='black', fg='white')
root.lab.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: The value of `icon` is `"03n"`. Of course tkinter does not know how to show that. You have to see in openweathermap's API docs how to fetch that icon.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22153656/3944322 to get the icon, use `f'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{icon}.png'` as url.

Comment: @zvone i tried visiting the doc page but couldnt get the code for python

Comment: @Stef I tried using that link for the image but unfortunately couldnt get the results. I would be grateful if would help me out some more because i am relatively new to python. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: fetch weather icons from openweathermap

According to the comments:

- The value of icon is "03n". Of course tkinter does not know how to show that. You have to see in openweathermap's API docs how to fetch that icon. – @zvone
- see SO:Answer [set a tkinter app icon with a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22153656/3944322) to get the icon.
  use `f'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{icon}.png'` as url. – @Stef

---

### [image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests, base64

class OpenWeatherMap:
    APPID = 'c73d9cdb31fd6a386bee66158b116cd0'

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid={appid}&q={city}&units=metric"
        self.json = {}

    def get_city(self, city):
        url = self.url.format(appid=OpenWeatherMap.APPID, city=city)
        self.json = requests.get(url).json()
        return self.json

    def get(self, key):
        return self.json['main'][key]

    def get_icon_data(self):
        icon_id = self.json['weather'][0]['icon']
        url = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{icon}.png'.format(icon=icon_id)
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        return base64.encodebytes(response.raw.read())


class OWIconLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        weather_icon = kwargs.pop('weather_icon', None)
        if weather_icon is not None:
            self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=weather_icon)
            kwargs['image'] = self.photo

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("220x120+0+0")
        self.configure(bg='black')

        owm = OpenWeatherMap()
        owm.get_city('karachi')

        temperature = owm.get('temp')

        temp_icon = OWIconLabel(self, weather_icon=owm.get_icon_data())
        temp_icon.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.temp = tk.Label(self,
                             text='{} deg celcius'.format(temperature),
                             font=("Helvetica", 15), bg='black', fg='white')
        self.temp.grid(row=1, column=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***