# Weather issue - from weather import Weather, Unit ImportError: cannot import name 'Weather' from 'weather'

Tags: python, weather, weather-api

I get this error:

> from weather import Weather, Unit ImportError: cannot import name
>   'Weather' from 'weather'
>   (C:Users\Python\Python37\site-packages\weather__init__.py)

I have installed weather using pip and I still get the error. I am trying to install weather-api but there is no matching distribution found for weather-api.

```
from weather import Weather, Unit
import time

class WeatherData:
temperature = 0
weather_conditions = ''
wind_speed = 0
city = ''

def __init__(self, city):
    self.city = city
    weather = Weather(unit = Unit.CELSIUS)
    lookup = weather.lookup_by_location(self.city)
    self.temperature = lookup.condition.temp
    self.weather_conditions = lookup.condition.text
    self.wind_speed = lookup.wind.speed

def getTemperature(self):
    return self.temperature + " C"

def getWeatherConditions(self):
    return self.weather_conditions

def getWindSpeed(self):
    return self.wind_speed + " kph"

def getCity(self):
    return self.city

def getTime(self):
    return time.ctime()
if __name__ == "__main__":
current_weather = WeatherData('London')
print(current_weather.getTemperature())
print(current_weather.getWeatherConditions())
print(current_weather.getTime())
```

Comment: did you try this `pip install python3-weather-api` ?

Comment: i installed it just now, same error

Comment: Then there is an issue either with your venv or the your installed packages. i tried it right now and it works fine. try to uninstall the other weather packages you installed earlier

Comment: actually I would recommend to NOT use the package. i tried some examples which dont work anymore due to different reasons. maybe its easier to get weather information using some api

Comment: @SuzanaKamis: Relevant [fetch weather icons from openweathermap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252135/7414759)

Comment: From what I've seen (repo 404), this library seems abandoned.

Comment: You are actually mixing Yahoo API and OpenWeatherMap API. In Yahoo API python wrapper does not have the concept of "Unit". And Yahoo API is not responding anymore.